# Can Python slicing be used to skip one specific element by index?

Tags: python

Suppose I am writing a recursive function where I want to pass a `list` to a function with a single element missing, as part of a loop. Here is one possible solution:

```
def Foo(input):
    if len(input) == 0: return
    for j in input:
       t = input[:]
       t.remove(j)
       Foo(t)
```

Is there a way to abuse the slice operator to pass the list minus the element `j` without explicitly copying the list and removing the item from it?

Comment: What exactly you are trying to do? There might be a better way to actually do it?

Comment: It scares me to see the name of a builtin used as a variable name.  Please consider using `lst` or `L` as your variable rather than "shadowing" the `list` builtin.

Comment: I am recursively exploring the space of an NP-complete problem. But in this question, I am just trying to avoid creating an extra variable unnecessarily. I also corrected the error in the code.

Comment: Are you trying to enumerate the power set of the input?

Comment: Actually, I am trying to enumerate all possible pairings of two sets.

Comment: If you are trying to enumerate pairings you should definitely look at the stuff in the `itertools` module.  Perhaps `itertools.product()` will help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What about this?

```
for i in range(len(list_)):
    Foo(list_[:i] + list_[i+1:])
```

You are stilling copying items, though you ignore the element at index `i` while copying.

**BTW**, you can always try to avoid overriding built-in names like `list` by appending underscores.

Comment: I'm not trying to improve efficiency, just trying to avoid an extra variable.

Comment: This answer avoids binding an extra variable name.  It does create an extra `list` instance of course.

Comment: I just tested this with an input list of a single element, and it correctly returned the empty list for me.  And looking at the code, that is exactly what I expect.  Mind you, it only works if you correctly specify the index to skip as 0 (the only valid index for a length-1 list).  If you specify an index outside the list, you get the whole list, so perhaps this is what happened to you when you tested it?

Comment: This answer works correctly. I did something stupid earlier (forgot to use `enumerate`).

Answer (score 5):

If your lists are small, I recommend using the approach in the answer from @satoru.

If your lists are very large, and you want to avoid the "churn" of creating and deleting list instances, how about using a generator?

```
import itertools as it
def skip_i(seq, i):
    return it.chain(it.islice(seq, 0, i), it.islice(seq, i+1, None))
```

This pushes the work of skipping the i'th element down into the C guts of `itertools`, so this should be faster than writing the equivalent in pure Python.

To do it in pure Python I would suggest writing a generator like this:

```
def gen_skip_i(seq, i):
    for j, x in enumerate(seq):
        if i != j:
            yield x
```

EDIT: Here's an improved version of my answer, thanks to @Blckknght in comments below.

```
import itertools as it
def skip_i(iterable, i):
    itr = iter(iterable)
    return it.chain(it.islice(itr, 0, i), it.islice(itr, 1, None))
```

This is a big improvement over my original answer.  My original answer only worked properly on indexable things like lists, but this will work correctly for any iterable, including iterators!  It makes an explicit iterator from the iterable, then (in a "chain") pulls the first `i` values, and skips only a single value before pulling all remaining values.

Thank you very much @Blckknght!

Comment: In this particular case, my inputs were small, but I will definitely keep this solution in mind if I try this on a larger sized input.

Comment: You could speed it up a bit further by reusing a single iterator for both `islice` calls. The first one would slice from `0` to `i`, the next would slice from `1` to `None`.

Comment: @Blckknght I can't figure out what you mean.  Maybe you could post an answer with code showing how your suggestion works?  I thought about making an iterator, pulling the first N items and yielding them, calling `next()` once to pull and discard the i-th item, then yielding all the rest... but I can't think of a way to do that using `itertools` tricks, and a pure Python `for` loop is slower than the C code in `itertools`.

Comment: It's just a minor variation on your code: `iterator=iter(seq); return it.chain(it.islice(iterator, 0, i), it.islice(iterator, 1, None))`. The benefit is that the second `islice` only needs to skip one value, not `i+1` of them.

Comment: @Blckknght that's slick!  Thank you for that.  Answer updated, with credit to you for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code equivalent to satoru's, but is faster, as it makes one copy of the list per iteration instead of two:

```
before = []
after = list_[:]

for x in range(0, len(list_)):
    v = after.pop(0)
    Foo(before + after)
    before.append(v)
```

(11ms instead of 18ms on my computer, for a list generated with `list(range(1000))`)

Comment: `after.pop(0)` still effectively copies the list (though perhaps it is a little more efficient than a slice, since it doesn't create a new object, just shifts references internally). Lists aren't optimized for additions or removals from anywhere but at the end.

Comment: However, it only has to copy a part of the list instead of all of it (the complexity order is the same, but it is still faster in practice)